# Speed difference MS SQL Server 2019 to PostgreSQL/PostGIS 12 for spatial data

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, postgis, spatial-query

I imported a shapefile with 3000 polygons in UTM 25832 into both databases MS SQL Server 2019 and PostgreSQL/PostGIS. Then I calculated a buffer of 1000 meters around these geometries and transferred the result to a new table. (Again in both databases with their integrated STBuffer()-ST_Buffer() functions)

Result PostGIS: 9 seconds, MS SQL 2019: 1 minute, MS SQL 2017: 1:09 minutes

All databases are running on the same PC and both MSSQL Server and Postgres/POSTGIS have been freshly set up. No optimizations were deliberately carried out. The test was carried out once with spatial indices and once without. (both times Postgres/PostGIS much faster)

Is it really possible that PostgreSQL/PostGIS is so much faster than MS SQL Server 2019 as far as geodata is concerned?

Comment: Without any indices, I wouldn't even start with a performance test, it hardly makes sense.

Comment: Is it really possible? Obviously it is - unless your test is completely bogus and is using completely different data in both databases. But you can probably find also queries that are faster on SQL Server than on Postgres.

Comment: Is it possible that Postgres runs this query in parallel and SQL Server does not? You would need to inspect the execution plans for both products.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Thanks for your input, in the meantime I have added spatial indices to both tables, the result that Postgres/Postgis is much faster has not changed.